# What's the simplest way to count the number of requests to /foo/ that Apache has served?

Tags: apache, grep, log-analysis, hit-count

I'm looking to retroactively parse the logs and count the number of /foo/* requests that have occurred to have a baseline benchmark for a new feature that we're pushing. A simple command line script would be fine -- with an added bonus for being able to specify a date-range.

Some use of grep, perhaps?

Comment: line 3: error: 'Simple' and 'able to specify a date-range': Incompatible types

Answer (score 2):

```
egrep -c '\] "[A-Z]+ /foo/' access_log
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "able to specify a date range" condition makes it a little harder.  Easiest probably to write a Python or Ruby program.  Otherwise, using date(1) with `-f` to set up the parsing format, `-j` to tell it to leave the damn clock alone, and `-r` to have it print seconds since epoch would get you there.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgrep " /foo/" access_log | wc -l
```

to get a roughly formatted accesses per day:

```
fgrep " /foo/" access_log | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c
```